# C# -infinite for loop

Tags: c#, infinite-loop

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int j, counter=0;
    j = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i=i*2)
    {
        j = j - i;
        while (j<25)
        {
            j = j + 5;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Test" + counter);
}
```

Hi.  I am trying to debug this code, but am not able to.

Can anybody please explain why this is causing an infinite loop?

Comment: It's because 0*2=0

Comment: Learn to use your environment's debugger. This will prove invaluable in the future.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you started `i` at zero; no matter how many times you double zero, it's going to stay zero :)

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i=i*2) {
    j = j - i;
    while (j<25) {
        j = j + 5;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Others have already explained the immediate cause. Let me just offer you an "algorithm" for hunting down these kinds of problems so you can solve them on your own in the future: use "Locals" or "Autos" or "Watch" or even "Immediate" panel in the debugger to inspect the values of the variables. You can also just place the mouse arrow over a variable and the hint that pops-up will allow you to see the current variable value.

Had you done that in this case, you'd have noticed that `i` is staying 0 forever and probably reached a conclusion about what is the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is your condition for i

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i=i*2)
```

on the first loop, i = 0, and 0*2 = 0, so i stays at 0 forever.